# What is the best practice for dealing with a spam question?

Tags: discussion

I have to review this question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/vashikaran-mantra-in-hindi-91-9636465464 what we should do for delete it vote for closing it is the right thing to do? I know that many question are closed but still visible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh no.

Please no.

Anything but Vashikaran. :o

---

To answer your question, **spam flag it**. 6 Spam flags delete and lock the post, and feed the post details (and user details) to a spam tracking system that gets smarter and is able to catch these posts with decreasing human intervention.

This *particular* spammer had barraged Physics and AskUbuntu a couple months ago, and was pretty persistent. Hopefully the new spam-battling can aid  us here.

Comment: Thanks so has non sense vote for closing it?

Comment: @GM You _can_, and it puts it in the queues for more people to see, but spamflagging should be enough.

Comment: @GM Unless I run out of flags, I'll be happy to spamflag the "guru" any time.